# merge two arrays into one array

Tags: php, xml

i have the following code that creates two arrays for each `RichText` element in my xml source.   One of the arrays is for an attribute with a prefix, and the other array is for the attributes that do not have any prefixes.  This is the only way I could figure out how to do it:

```
<?php
$url = "http://testvipd7.scene7.com/is/agm/papermusepress/HOL_12_F_green?&fmt=fxgraw";    
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);       
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('s7', 'http://ns.adobe.com/S7FXG/2008');
$textNode = $xml->xpath("//default:RichText[@s7:elementID]");

function pr($var) { print '<pre>'; print_r($var); print '</pre>'; }

$result = array();
$result1 = array();
foreach($textNode as $node){
    $result[] = $node->attributes('http://ns.adobe.com/S7FXG/2008');
    $result1[] = $node->attributes();

}

$text = array_merge($result,$result1);

pr($text);

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [caps] => none
                    [colorName] => 
                    [colorValue] => #518269
                    [colorspace] => rgb
                    [elementID] => smalltext
                    [fill] => true
                    [fillOverprint] => false
                    [firstBaselineOffset] => ascent
                    [joints] => miter
                    [maxFontSize] => 11
                    [miterLimit] => 4
                    [referencePoint] => inherit
                    [rowCount] => 1
                    [rowGap] => 18
                    [rowMajorOrder] => true
                    [stroke] => false
                    [strokeOverprint] => false
                    [warpBend] => 0.5
                    [warpDirection] => horizontal
                    [warpHorizontalDistortion] => 0
                    [warpStyle] => none
                    [warpVerticalDistortion] => 0
                    [weight] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [caps] => none
                    [colorName] => 
                    [colorValue] => #518269
                    [colorspace] => rgb
                    [elementID] => largetext
                    [fill] => true
                    [fillOverprint] => false
                    [firstBaselineOffset] => ascent
                    [joints] => miter
                    [maxFontSize] => 19
                    [miterLimit] => 4
                    [referencePoint] => inherit
                    [rowCount] => 1
                    [rowGap] => 18
                    [rowMajorOrder] => true
                    [stroke] => false
                    [strokeOverprint] => false
                    [warpBend] => 0.5
                    [warpDirection] => horizontal
                    [warpHorizontalDistortion] => 0
                    [warpStyle] => none
                    [warpVerticalDistortion] => 0
                    [weight] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 278.418
                    [y] => 115.542
                    [columnGap] => 18
                    [columnCount] => 1
                    [textAlign] => left
                    [fontFamily] => Trade Gothic LT Pro Bold Cn
                    [fontSize] => 11
                    [color] => #518269
                    [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
                    [width] => 212.582
                    [height] => 33
                )

        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 278.998
                    [y] => 86.7168
                    [columnGap] => 18
                    [columnCount] => 1
                    [textAlign] => left
                    [fontFamily] => Bootstrap
                    [fontSize] => 19
                    [color] => #518269
                    [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
                    [trackingRight] => 4%
                    [width] => 240
                    [height] => 29
                )

        )

)
```

My `array_merge` after the loop creates one huge array, with 4 nested arrays.  Two arrays are the default attributes of `RichText`, and the other two arrays are the attributes that have a `s7:` prefix.  But what I need is that `$result` and `$result1` be merged inside the foreach loop, that way there is just one merged array for each `$textNode` containing all the attributes.  Thus, in this example url I should have two arrays in the end because there are only two `RichText` elements.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit of your code:

```
$text[] = array_merge($result,$result1);
```

logically belongs to inside of your foreach loop as I guess you almost knew.  However, it does not work there.  SimpleXML likes to return SimpleXMLElement objects that can be iterated, but are not arrays themselves, so we need to replace `array_merge` by something else.

So all in all:

```
$attributesByNode = array();

foreach($textNode as $node) {
    $result1 = $node->attributes('http://ns.adobe.com/S7FXG/2008');
    $result2 = $node->attributes();

    foreach ($result1 as $attribName => $attributeValue) 
    { 
        $attributesByNode[$attribName] = $attribVal; 
    } 
    foreach ($result2 as $attribName => $attributeValue) 
    { 
        $attributesByNode[$attribName] = $attribVal; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: i made your recommended changes and when I do `print_r($attributesByNode);` all I get is: `Array ( [0] => [1] => )`.  Where did my data go?

Comment: @thindery - Oops, SimpleXML does not return arrays.  Fixed.